# Ruby Version Display

Tags: ruby-1.9.3

when I typed in `$ ruby -v` the output appeared as below:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

In the past, I used to see the output as:

```
ruby 1.9.3
```

Why is my ruby version appearing with more data now?  I am new to programming and am wondering if I messed up my computer.  Help!  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, you upgraded your Ruby installation somewhere along the line (or your system package manager did). It's very unlikely that you messed anything up.

Comment: Okay - Just wanted to make sure.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using RVM to manage your ruby versions? If not I would reccomend doing so. 
https://rvm.io/

Comment: I just checked and it looks like I have `rvm 1.16.16`.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not using RVM, and that the system package manager installed an update.  I would strongly recommend using RVM, it will save you tons of head ache in the future.

https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

If you are not familiar with it, it is a great version manager created by Wayne Seguin.  It allows you use specific versions of ruby and specific gems for different projects.